# How do I import a Camera from an external .blend file?

Tags: camera, import, linked-data

I tried to import a camera from an external .blend file via "link" and "append" but in both cases, nothing happens.

So how do I import a camera with all its settings into another blend file?

Answer (score 4):

You should append the camera from the *Object* Data-Block, not the *Camera* Data-Block.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to append, select the .blend file and go to the *Object* Data-Block folder and select the camera. Then hit *Append from Library*.

[image: Append camera]

When you append from the *Camera* Data-Block, you are appending the Camera's settings, like the *Focal Distance*, *Axis Shit*, perspective type clipping etc, but not the camera object itself.

[image: Append camera settings]

When you append from the *Object* Data-Block itself, you'll be appending the camera itself (the visible object in the 3D View), including it's settings.

[image: Append camera object]

Comment: can you explain why you shouldn't append from the ''camera'' directory?

Comment: @Delagone The camera directory contains the **settings** of the camera, not the camera object itself.

Comment: You've just opened up a couple more questions :) Could you elaborate on this in your answer? What settings would be appended and what will not? I think this would be useful to a lot of users.

Comment: updated the answer