# How to append a bezier curve from another .blend

Tags: modeling

When I try to append nothing happens. Tried 2.79, 2.81 and the latest 2.82 I just downloaded 5 minutes ago.

Steps:
1. start blender
2. try append a bezier curve called hhh_hhh (datablock is named hhh_ggg) from the file I added to this post
3. nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

Here is a sample file you can try append a bezier curve from:
https://we.tl/t-GWCIAgFzgB

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71000/how-do-i-import-a-camera-from-an-external-blend-file

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was because the author appended Curve data-block and can be solved by taking the correct curve object from Object data-block, as pointed to a similar question in the comment.

Comment: Yes. The user needs to know what things can and can not be appended and this info can only be learned from stack exhange question that is about totally separate issue that just happens to be about data blocks.

Comment: it is a papercut of user experience, I know, soon we'll use Asset Manager and hope it's more intuitive, at least the proposal of the UX is promising